# jquery collect all option values from select box in a JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a select box.

```
<select id='x'>
    <option value='1'>'Vineet'</option>
    <option value='2'>'Vivek'</option>
    <option value='3'>'Madhu'</option>
</select>
```

The options are added dynamically to it. At the end, I want to collect the values of ALL option elements contained within this select box into an array. I searched the forum for the answer, but Q/A are there for getting the 'selected' option only.

I tried this:

```
var myList = [];
$('#x').each(function() { myList.push( $(this).value() ) });
```

In firebug, It gives this error:

> missing } after property list

But I fail to see any missing `}`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: do you add an ',' after every value ?

Comment: There is no comma in any of the value of <option>

Comment: $(this).val() and not  $(this).value()

Comment: Further to this, if I have to get the class of every <option>, will something like this work? -- "$('#x option').class()"

Comment: What if an element has more than one class assigned? eg class="myBold myLargeFont myGreen" - look at attr for jquery: http://api.jquery.com/attr/  - also look at .hasClass

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to loop through each `option` element within the select, not just the select itself, also, the correct method to get the value of an input in jQuery is `val()`, try this:

```
myList = [];
$('#x option').each(function() {
  myList.push($(this).val())
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yFp79/1/)

You can also use `map()`:

```
var myList = $('#x option').map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get();

// A version of the above in ES6 (note: unsupported in IE)
let myList = $('#x option').map((i, el) => el.value).get();
```

In all the above cases the `myList` variable will contain an array of strings.

Comment: What error did you get? Are you sure you tried that exact solution - as you can see from the fiddle, it does work.

Comment: Oops. My bad there. I supplied only ('#x') instead of ('#x option').  Now it worked. Thanks Rory.

Answer (score 1):

Try jQuery function for getting the value of an element (wrapped in a jQuery object) is `.val()`, not `.value()` - that may be causing some confusion, though I can't be sure.

As a side note, your selector is incorrect for what you want. `$('#x')` will return all of the elements that have an `id` of `x` - which should only ever be one element - then the `.each()` will iterate over that set of elements (so it will call the function once). You'll just end up with an array that contains a single value, which will be the currently selected value of the `<select>` input.

Instead, use `$('#x > option')` which will return all `<option>` elements that are immediate children of the `<select>` element with the `id` of `x`.

Comment: It worked after corrections suggested by you.  Thank You Anthony.

Comment: Dear Anthony, Answers given by yourself & Rony are same (no wonder in that). While accepting answer, since only a single answer can be accepted, I chose the first-one.  But equal credit goes to you.  Thank You.

Comment: Extending this, if I have to get the class of every <option>, will something like this work? --  "$('#x option').class()"